# Create a Pixel 4 Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-10.0, google-pixel

I'm trying to create a Pixel 4 virtual device in Android Studio 3.6.2. However, the Pixel 4 doesn't appear to be an option. Is there any way to download the Hardware Profile for this device.

[Virtual Device Configuration Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HBYW.png)

Edit: As of Android Studio 4.1 (Released Aug 2020), you can now create a virtual device with with a Pixel 4 Skin.

Comment: Since Android Studio 4.1 you can have the Pixel 4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to do that until they upload the official device skin.

However, you can search the internet for the specifications of the emulator for Pixel 4 and then configure an existing emulator with that specs.

However, there no way by which you can get the skin of the device before Google Uploads it officially.